# Rails doesn't load classes on deserializing YAML/Marshal objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, classloader, deserialization

- Rails: 3.0.3
- Ruby: 1.9.2

Trying to deserialize a very simple object using `YAML.load` or `Marshal.load` produces a corrupted object because the class which belongs to is not required on the deserializing process.

Example:

```
# app/models/my_model.rb
class MyModel
  attr_accessor :id
end

# test/unit/serializing_test.rb
require 'test_helper'

class SerializingTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def test_yaml_serialize_structure
    my_model = MyModel.new
    my_model.id = 'my model'

    File.open( "#{Rails.root}/tmp/object.yml" , 'w' ) do |f|
      YAML::dump(my_model, f)
    end
  end

  def test_yaml_deserialize_structure
    object = YAML.load_file "#{Rails.root}/tmp/object.yml"
    assert( object.instance_of? MyModel )
    assert_equal( 'my model', object.id )
  end
end
```

With this code we can run this shell console session without any error:

```
$ ruby -Itest test/unit/serializing_test.rb -n test_yaml_serialize_structure
$ ruby -Itest test/unit/serializing_test.rb -n test_yaml_deserialize_structure
```

But if I run the *deserialization calls* from a Rails console the object is not deserialized properly because the class is never required:

```
$ rails c
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > object = YAML.load_file "#{Rails.root}/tmp/object.yml"
 => #<Syck::Object:0x0000010322ea30 @class="MyModel", @ivars={"id"=>"my model"}>
```

I know the only problem is that the class is not required because if I require it by hand everything works:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > require "#{Rails.root}/app/models/my_model"
 => ["MyModel"] 
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > object = YAML.load_file "#{Rails.root}/tmp/object.yml"
 => #<MyModel:0x0000010320c8e0 @id="my model">
```

I have presented only the YAML examples but with Marshal is pretty the same.

Also say that although I'm reproducing the problem in a *Rails console* originally this problem was turning me crazy in a normal request to my application.

So the question is: *How can I deserialize objects in Rails without have to require all my classes by hand?*

Thanks

f.

Comment: I just have realized that this only happend in a **development environment**.

Comment: I'm seeing that if I active `config.cache_classes` the deserialization works well, but of course: **I lost the class auto refresing** :/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Well, after read **@tadman** and a bunch of answers I have received in the spanish ror mailing list [1] I have collected a few hot tips when you have to deal with Ruby deserializing and class loading in Rails:

**Super fast solution**

Use `config.cache_classes = true` in your `development.rb` but you will lost the class auto-refreshing.

**Better solution**

Require all the classes that are gonna be deserialized but not with `require` but with `require_dependency`[2] so in *development* environment the class auto-refreshing will remain working.

**Elegant solution**

Monkey-patch the *YAML* and the *Marshal* gem to tell them to call `require_dependency` when they find a non-defined class to deserialize.

And **@Xavi** has sent me a proposition of monkey-patch `Marshal` (he says he wrote it on the air and it is not tested so use it in your own risk) [3]

- [1] http://lists.simplelogica.net/pipermail/ror-es/2011-January/024787.html
- [2] http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Dependencies/Loadable/require_dependency
- [3] http://lists.simplelogica.net/pipermail/ror-es/2011-January/024796.html

Comment: This answer is a lifesaver. Thought I was going to have to rethink my architecture...

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I needed! However, I'm a bit confused by what is doing the 'requiring' in suggestion #2.

Comment: FYI, @fguillen got back to me and here are a couple of solutions: `* in a custom initializer like: '/config/initializers/explicit_requires.rb'
* at the bottom of the '/config/application.rb'`

Answer (score 2):

I described this "issue" on GitHub: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/1585

Answer (score 2):

To automatically require classes on YAML loading in the manner **@fguillen** suggests is elegant, I wrote this short monkey-patch.

It simply attempts to require_dependency any class the Psych ToRuby class resolves to classes.

Works for me in a serialised Active Record that stores a custom class instance, YMMV.

```
module Psych::Visitors
  ToRuby.class_eval do
    alias :resolve_class_without_autoload :resolve_class
    def resolve_class klassname
      begin
        require_dependency klassname.underscore 
      rescue NameError, LoadError
      end
      resolve_class_without_autoload klassname
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to adapt @ben-patterson's answer a bit to make it work (using Rails 5.0.2):

```
module Psych::Visitors
    ToRuby.class_eval do
        def resolve_class(klassname)
            begin
                class_loader.load klassname
            rescue ArgumentError
                require_dependency klassname.underscore
                klassname.constantize
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, both YAML and Marshal do not make use of the Rails autoloader. You must go ahead and pre-load any classes that might need to be deserialized.

It's a bit if a fuss, especially in the development environment where almost nothing is loaded before it is needed.

Answer (score 0):

In rails version 7 the monkey patch has to catch Psych::DisallowedClass error instead of ArgumentError or NameError, LoadError as proposed by
@ben-patterson and @panzi

```rb
module Psych::Visitors
  ToRuby.class_eval do
    def resolve_class(klassname)
      begin
        class_loader.load klassname
      rescue Psych::DisallowedClass => e
        require_dependency klassname.underscore
        klassname.constantize
      end
    end
  end
end
```