# Rails ActiveRecord serialize method doesn't work in test environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, serialization, activerecord

I've got a problem with deserialization of ActiveRecord [serialize](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/serialize/class) method in my tests.
It just gives me pure String instead of my data Array.

Example:

```
User > ActiveRecord::Base
   serialize :roles, Array
end
```

Console:

```
u = User.new
u.roles = ["admin", "support"]
u.save
# => true

User.first.roles
# => ["admin", "support"]
```

In test environment:

```
User.first.roles
# => "--- \n- admin\n- support\n"
```

it is a String. It seems that YAML serialize is not working there but I have no idea what to do to get it working.

I was already trying to figure it out with [this](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/5002-nested-objects-dont-deserialized-completely-rails-3-beta-4), [this](http://itsignals.cascadia.com.au/?p=10), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705867/rails-doesnt-load-classes-on-deserializing-yaml-marshal-objects) and [this](http://blog.sbf5.com/?p=39), but with no luck.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.
Martin

Comment: What version of rails are you using?  Your ruby version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After all to bypass this I needed to call the data in database directly without involvement of "serialize" AR method.

```
YAML::load(User.first.roles_before_type_cast)
```

And now test environment also directly parses the data and give me correct roles Array.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if it solves your problem, but you can always get back the array from the string using

```
YAML::load("--- \n- admin\n- support\n")
# => ["admin", "support"]
```

So, in your test environment, you should do

```
YAML::load(User.first.roles)
```

Comment: It won't work because AR serialize method automatically uses the YAML parsing when trying to get data by: User.first.roles

Comment: Exactly, in test environment it returns just string but I cannot make the double YAML::load on object which works in development and production.
  
It is dirty trick to make the YAML parsing by hand in second method in my object.